# Powershell: How to create an empty Excel worksheet-XML via XmlTextWriter?

Tags: xml, powershell, asynchronous, worksheet, xmltextwriter

I am currently writing a Powershell code to import a very large DataTable into an Excel-File without having Excel installed on that machine. All is fine till now, except that I dont know how to create the worksheet.xml structure via an XmlTextWriter.

This is the final XML structure that I need to create via XmlTextWriter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" >
    <sheetData/>
</worksheet>
```

This is the Powershell code that I have till now for that part:

```
# create the settings:
$settings = [System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings]::new()
$settings.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$settings.Async = $true

# create the XML: 
$sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$wr = [System.Xml.XmlTextWriter]::create($sb, $settings)
[void]$wr.WriteStartDocumentAsync($true)
[void]$wr.WriteStartElement("worksheet") #, "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main")
[void]$wr.WriteStartAttribute("r", "xmlns", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/2006/relationships")
[void]$wr.WriteStartElementAsync($null, "sheetdata", $null)
[void]$wr.WriteEndElementAsync()
[void]$wr.WriteEndElementAsync()
$wr.Flush()

# show result:
$sb.ToString()
```

But the result is not the expected XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?><worksheet r:xmlns="" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/2006/relationships"><sheetdata /></worksheet>
```

1. The encoding is still UTF-16 instead of UTF-8
2. I am getting an extra "r:xmlns"-entry (?)
3. I am not able to create the
   "xmlns"-entry PLUS the "xmlns:r"-entry for the same element
4. not all calls are running/are available in Async-Mode.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Your remaining problem is caused by <worksheet> being in the default namespace (http://schemas.openxmlformats...), while <sheetdata> is in no namespace. Try adding that same namespace to <sheetdata>.

Comment: Thanky you, but I think I have to accept that extra entry. Otherwise I had to do the same for all following childNodes (some thousands of rows) which I want to avoid for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final code I came up with based on the input from wasmachien:

```
# create the settings:
$settings = [System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings]::new()
$settings.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$settings.Indent = $true
$settings.Async  = $true

# the XmlWriter MUST be based on a stream to allow custom encodings:
$stream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
$writer = [System.Xml.XmlTextWriter]::create($stream, $settings)

# create the XML:
[void]$writer.WriteStartDocumentAsync($true)
[void]$writer.WriteStartElementAsync($null, "worksheet", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main")
[void]$writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync("xmlns", "r", $null, "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/2006/relationships")
[void]$writer.WriteStartElementAsync($null, "sheetdata", $null)
[void]$writer.WriteEndElementAsync()
[void]$writer.WriteEndElementAsync()
[void]$writer.WriteEndDocumentAsync()
[void]$writer.Flush()

# show result:
cls
$utf8 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$utf8.GetString($stream.ToArray())
$stream.Dispose()
```

Here is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/2006/relationships" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <sheetdata xmlns="" />
</worksheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

`xmlns` and `xmlns:r` are not attributes, they are namespace declarations.

A plain `xmlns` sets the default namespace (every element in the document with no specific namespace gets this one.). Namespace declarations of the form `xmlns:xxx` mean that every element in your document that is prefixed with `xxx` is in this namespace.

The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter.writestartelement?view=netcore-3.1) suggests how to write these as follows:

```
//Write an element (this one is the root).
writer.WriteStartElement("bookstore");

//Write the namespace declaration.
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "bk", null, "urn:samples");

writer.WriteStartElement("book");
```

The encoding is in UTF-16 because you are writing the XML to a StringBuilder (and C# uses UTF-16 strings under the hood). If you write it to a stream, UTF-8 should be enabled by default.

```
$stream = [System.IO.File]::create("output.xml")
$wr = [System.Xml.XmlTextWriter]::create([System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($stream), $settings)
```

Don't forget to close your stream at the end: `$stream.close()`